# How to hide "Messages" section in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I am using Phabricator for a long time. It was working fine until I mistakenly press some key combination on my keyboard. Now it shows me "Messages" section all the time (Code review mode, tickets details mode and etc.). It cuts a lot of useful space.
I tried to find answer on 'Phabricator User Documentation' but no success.
Does anybody know how to hide "Messages" section?
I am using Safari 8.0.7 on OS X 10.10.4.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use "?" to bring up keyboard shortcuts for that screen.

"\" toggles the Conpherence panel on/off.